# What is the type promotion rule for a parenthesized sub-expression?

Tags: c, types, integer-promotion, type-promotion

Assume an integer expression comprised of multiple unsigned integral types `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`. The expression contains a parenthesized sub-expression, within which all elements are of type `uint16_t`.

Should the elements inside the parenthesized sub-expression be promoted to `uint32_t` prior to evaluating the sub-expression?

For example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint16_t a16 = 0x2000;
    uint16_t b16 = 0x3000;
    uint32_t c32 = 0x00000001;
    uint32_t d32;

    // Should (a16 * b16) be evaluated to 0x06000000, or to 0x0000?
    // Should d32 be evaluated to 0x06000001, or to 0x00000001?
    d32 = c32 + (a16 * b16);

    printf("d32=0x%08x\n", d32);

    return 0;
}
```

Trying this in *ideone* online compiler suggests that `a16` and `b16` are promoted to `uint32_t` prior to the multiplication. Is this mandated by the C standard? Why not evaluate to `uint16_t` while inside the parentheses?

Comment: Note that the parentheses are irrelevant, since the normal precedence rules make it group the multiplication first.

Comment: Suppose you have the slighty different `d32 = b16 * (a16 + a16);` Isn't it obvious the parentheses are they to ensure the addition is performed first, not to restrict the sum to 16 bits?

Comment: @Barmar - the question is more general than this specific multiplication example. I could make it an overflowing addition instead and switch places with the c32 term.

Comment: @WeatherVane - no, it is not obvious, actually. One could think that calculations are done sequentially, and at each step, the compiler would apply the necessary promotion rules.

Comment: My favourite bug I fixed last year was effectively `bonus = 1/2 * salary;` where `salary` was a `double` type. This is a touchstone for appreciating that implicit type conversion happens step by step.

Comment: @Bathsheba - great example to what I suspected. But then, how does this agree with your answer below? Or does it only refer to integer promotions?

Comment: @ysap: My bonus example is grouped as `(1/2) * salary` - that's specified by the grammar. The `1/2` is converted implicitly to `0.0` prior to its multiplication.

Comment: @Bathsheba - exactly my point. The compiler first performs integer division and then promotes the result to a double for further evaluation.

Comment: I talked this over with some folks who know a fair amount of C, and they tended to agree that your latter edits changed the meaning of the question to the point where you invalidated some of the answers. If the answers have raised a new question, please ask them in a different question. Thanks.

Comment: @Machavity - thanks for taking the time to deal with this. FWIW, I do not agree with your assertion, but I won't argue. Asking the same question with a small variation, as the final revision here was, will end up folks flagging the question as duplicate. Anyway, I already got the information I needed so moving forward. If some alien form the future would like to make sense of later comments and answers, they are welcome to read the revisions log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime a type smaller than `int` is used an an expression it is first promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` regardless of the context of the expression.

This is spelled out in section 6.3.1.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or
> `unsigned int` may be used
>
> - An object  or  expression  with  an  integer  type  (other  than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose  integer  conversion  rank  is  less
>   than  or  equal  to  the  rank  of `int` and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`,or `unsigned int`.
>
> If  an `int` can  represent  all  values  of  the  original  type  (as
> restricted  by  the  width,  for  a bit-field),  the  value  is
> converted  to  an `int`; otherwise,  it  is  converted  to  an
> `unsigned int`. These  are  called  the *integer promotions.* All
> other  types  are  unchanged  by  the integer promotions

So in your case, `a16` and `b16` will both be promoted to `int` before being applied to any operator, assuming that `int` is larger than `uint16_t`.

Note that that this is **integer promotions**, which is not the same as the **usual arithmetic conversions**.  The latter dictates how two operands of different types are converted to a common type before applying the operator.

Comment: But does a `uint16_t` rank higher than a 16 bit 1's complement `int`? Nice answer though, better than mine.

Comment: Thanks. "assuming that int is larger than uint16_t" - that's a key point here. I could change the question to use `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` instead, or assume a machine with 16-bit `int`s. What happens then?

Comment: @ysap In that case there's no promotion.  So given `uint32_t a, b;` and `uint64_t c`, in the expression `(a + b) + c`, The addition of `a+b` is done with type `uint32_t`, then the result is converted to `uint64_t` before being added to `c`.

Comment: Great, I just confirmed that in _ideone_. I'll update the question.

Comment: Re Anytime a type smaller than `int` is used an an expression it is first promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` regardless of the context of the expression”: This does not occur for parentheses, `_Generic`, array subscripting, arguments to prototyped functions not corresponding to `...`, increment and decrement operators (which require an lvalue and so could not tolerate a conversion of the value), unary `&`, `sizeof`, casts, addition or subtraction of an integer type to a pointer, `&&`, `||`, simple assignment, and the comma operator. But any other time, sure.

Answer (score 3):

All types narrower than `int` are promoted to an `int` prior to the multiplication.

So if you have a 32 bit 2's complement `int` then the result is effectively a product of two `int32_t` types.

The parentheses in your expression have no effect on either this implicit type conversion, or the final result.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying that all type promotions are performed prior to the evaluation of the expression, or any of its parts. Is that true? Can you point to the place in the standard (or some other reputable reference)?

Comment: @ysap: Multiplication is a binary operator. The types of the arguments go through the implicit conversion stage prior to the multiplication. The same is true for the addition. The operator precedence and associativity are hardwired into the language grammar, so it's difficult to point to a specific reference other than that.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with operand precedence nor specific (multiplication) operation. I'll edit the question to emphasize this.

Answer (score 1):

> Assume an integer expression comprised of multiple unsigned integral
> types uint16_t and uint32_t. The expression contains a parenthesized
> sub-expression, within which all elements are of type uint16_t.
>
> Should the elements inside the parenthesized sub-expression be
> promoted to uint32_t prior to evaluating the sub-expression?

No.  There are two main possibilities:

1. `uint16_t` is the same type as `unsigned int`.  In this case, no promotions are performed in evaluating operations with two `uint16_t` operands, and the result has type `uint16_t`.
2. `int` is wider than `uint16_t`, and can therefore represent all the values representable by `uint16_t`.  In this case, when both operands of a binary operator have type `uint16_t`, both are promoted to `int` (which is definitely not the same as `uint32_t`), and the result of the operation has type `int`.

In principle, C does not exclude a third possibility that in practice you will never see:

3. `uint16_t` is not the same type as `unsigned int`, but is the same size.  In this case you will either have promotion to `unsigned int` (which cannot be the same as `uint32_t` in this case) or no promotion.

Under no circumstance permitted to a conforming C implementation will the operands in question be promoted to `uint32_t`, nor will the operations with two `uint16_t` operands yield a `uint32_t` result.

Comment: Thanks. I think this agrees and expands on @dbush's answer.

Comment: It does agree.  It just focuses on an analysis of the implications of the Standard instead of on the provisions themselves.